# Using multipart with for loop

Tags: android, multipart, okhttp

I am using OKHTTP and using Multipart to send image to server.
My code is as follows :

```
RequestBody requestBody = null;
for (int i = 0; i < noOfItems; i++) {
                requestBody = new MultipartBuilder().type(MultipartBuilder.FORM)
                        .addFormDataPart("func", "savepacket")
                        .addFormDataPart("userid", String.valueOf(mLoginPref.getInt("userId", 1)))
                        .addFormDataPart("packname", strPackname)
                        .addFormDataPart("image", str + ".png", RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/png"), imagePath))
                        .addFormDataPart("count", String.valueOf(noOfItems))
                        .addFormDataPart("item_name" + String.valueOf(i + 1), al.get(i).getStrItemName())
                        .addFormDataPart("tag_item" + String.valueOf(i + 1), al.get(i).getStrItemTag())
                        .addFormDataPart("note" + String.valueOf(i + 1), al.get(i).getStrComment())
                        .addFormDataPart("image" + String.valueOf(i + 1), al.get(i).getStrItemName() + ".png", RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/png"), al.get(i).getStrItemImage()))
                        .build();
            }
            mstrQRResponse = HttpUtils.postRun("pack", requestBody);
```

As From code,(al is ArrayList) You can see that I have to send multiple items with single Packname, thats why I am using for loop.

But, actually only last item is saved on Server due to requestBody gets overrides inside for loop.

How all the items will be send by adding it to requestbody ?

Comment: Inside for loop, every time you are creating object of `requestBody`, and after it you are calling `postRun()`. Thats why the last item is uploading to server.

Comment: ya, thats ri8.. But How can I solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this may it will help you.

```
MultipartBuilder multipartBuilder = new MultipartBuilder().type(MultipartBuilder.FORM);
    RequestBody requestBody = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < noOfItems; i++) {
        multipartBuilder
                .addFormDataPart("func", "savepacket")
                .addFormDataPart("userid", String.valueOf(mLoginPref.getInt("userId", 1)))
                .addFormDataPart("packname", strPackname)
                .addFormDataPart("image", str + ".png", RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/png"), imagePath))
                .addFormDataPart("count", String.valueOf(noOfItems))
                .addFormDataPart("item_name" + String.valueOf(i + 1), al.get(i).getStrItemName())
                .addFormDataPart("tag_item" + String.valueOf(i + 1), al.get(i).getStrItemTag())
                .addFormDataPart("note" + String.valueOf(i + 1), al.get(i).getStrComment())
                .addFormDataPart("image" + String.valueOf(i + 1), al.get(i).getStrItemName() + ".png", RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/png"), al.get(i).getStrItemImage()));
    }
    requestBody = multipartBuilder.build();
    mstrQRResponse = HttpUtils.postRun("pack", requestBody);
```

Comment: Thanks bro.. Added all the items successfully on server.